# copy the segment of the file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a multi-line pdb file in the following format

```
ATOM   2381  CG2 THR A 304       3.359  -8.466 -13.379  1.00 34.89           C  
ATOM   2380  OG1 THR A 304       5.073 -10.157 -13.609  1.00 36.00           O  
...
ATOM   2380  OG1 THR A 304       5.073 -10.157 -13.609  1.00 36.00           O  
TER   
HETATM 2382  O   HOH A 572       2.739   5.289  20.202  1.00 33.02           O  
HETATM 2389  H01 HOH A 572       2.967   5.272  19.270  1.00 33.02           H  
HETATM 2390  H02 HOH A 572       2.017   5.906  20.344  1.00 33.02           H  
HETATM 2383  O   HOH A 619       9.589  -1.213  21.275  1.00 28.34           O  
HETATM 2391  H01 HOH A 619       9.100  -1.521  22.041  1.00 28.34           H  
HETATM 2392  H03 HOH A 619       9.669  -0.257  21.309  1.00 28.34           H  
HETATM 2384  O   HOH A 634       8.859   1.214  21.216  1.00 27.10           O  
HETATM 2393  H01 HOH A 634       9.495   1.911  21.394  1.00 27.10           H  
HETATM 2394  H02 HOH A 634       8.631   0.771  22.037  1.00 27.10           H  
HETATM 2385  O   HOH A 660      10.309  -1.469  23.867  1.00 43.45           O  
HETATM 2395  H01 HOH A 660       9.648  -1.616  24.547  1.00 43.45           H  
HETATM 2396  H02 HOH A 660      10.465  -0.527  23.770  1.00 43.45           H  
END
```

Using some utility I need to copy all lines after TER record (they may be defined as the lines started from HETATM) and save it in the separate file, containing:

```
HETATM 2382  O   HOH A 572       2.739   5.289  20.202  1.00 33.02           O  
HETATM 2389  H01 HOH A 572       2.967   5.272  19.270  1.00 33.02           H  
HETATM 2390  H02 HOH A 572       2.017   5.906  20.344  1.00 33.02           H  
HETATM 2383  O   HOH A 619       9.589  -1.213  21.275  1.00 28.34           O  
HETATM 2391  H01 HOH A 619       9.100  -1.521  22.041  1.00 28.34           H  
HETATM 2392  H03 HOH A 619       9.669  -0.257  21.309  1.00 28.34           H  
HETATM 2384  O   HOH A 634       8.859   1.214  21.216  1.00 27.10           O  
HETATM 2393  H01 HOH A 634       9.495   1.911  21.394  1.00 27.10           H  
HETATM 2394  H02 HOH A 634       8.631   0.771  22.037  1.00 27.10           H  
HETATM 2385  O   HOH A 660      10.309  -1.469  23.867  1.00 43.45           O  
HETATM 2395  H01 HOH A 660       9.648  -1.616  24.547  1.00 43.45           H  
HETATM 2396  H02 HOH A 660      10.465  -0.527  23.770  1.00 43.45           H
```

what unix utility may be useful for this?

Comment: Does the PDB contain other HETATM lines that you don't need?

Comment: No, there are only one place at the end of the file between TER and END records like it was shown in the example...

Comment: Then a simple `grep '^HETATM' file.pdb` would suffice

Comment: And how is this different from your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680160/unix-merge-two-files-based-on-the-selected-fragment/70680431#70680431

Comment: you may post the version with grep since it did what I was looking for! Bravo!!